# Custom data binding with Teleriks Grid

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, .net-4.0

I have an MVC3 Telerik app. This is my controller:

```
    [GridAction]
    public ActionResult Index(GridCommand command)
    {
        IEnumerable<Order> data = GetData(command);
        var dataContext = new NorthwindDataContext();

        //Required for pager configuration
        ViewData["total"] = dataContext.Orders.Count();

        return View(data);
    }

    [GridAction(EnableCustomBinding = true)]
    public ActionResult _CustomBinding(GridCommand command)
  {
IEnumerable<Order> data = GetData(command);

var dataContext = new NorthwindDataContext();
return View(new GridModel 
{ 
    Data = data, 
    Total = dataContext.Orders.Count() 
});
}

    //Utility method which does custom paging and sorting using Linq
    private static IEnumerable<Order> GetData(GridCommand command)
    {
        var dataContext = new NorthwindDataContext();
        IQueryable<Order> data = dataContext.Orders;


        if (command.PageSize > 0)
        {
            data = data.Skip((command.Page - 1) * command.PageSize);
        }

        data = data.Take(5);
        return data;
    }
```

This is my razor View:

```
    @model IEnumerable<Telerik.Order>

     @(Html.Telerik().Grid(Model)
    .Name("Grid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(o => o.OrderID).Width(100);
        columns.Bound(o => o.Customer.ContactName).Width(200);
        columns.Bound(o => o.ShipAddress);
        columns.Bound(o => o.OrderDate).Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}").Width(100);
    })
                .DataBinding(dataBinding =>
                {
                    dataBinding.Ajax().Select("_CustomBinding", "Home").Enabled(true);
            })
        .Pageable(pager => pager.Total((int)ViewData["total"]))
        .EnableCustomBinding(true)
        .Sortable()
```

)

When I run the app, it loads fine, but when I click on a number in the paging row at the bottom, I get :

```
 Error! The requested URL returned 500- Internal server error
```

It calls my function _CustomBinding and doesnt throw an error when i step through it. Whats causing this error?

Answer (score 0):

This means that a server side exception has occurred in _CustomBinding method. You can check what the actual server response is - it would contain the stacktrace. Use Fiddler or your browser's developer tools to check what the server response is.